# WEBMETHOD: Add details of two columns into third column

Tags: c#, webmethod, insert-select

I found many answers related to this but its not working pretty well with my code.

I WANT THE CODE IN MY WEBMETHOD in C# which I will be calling on android platform.

I have two columns, Firstname and Lastname.
I wish to combine the data of this two columns and INSERT it into third column Fullname.

I get the combination from the following code.

`SELECT firstname + lastname AS fullname FROM name`

And I wish to insert this in the third column of database.

But when I try the foll. code, the data gets entered into a new row instead 
of the row that already has the firstname and lastname inserted.

So what can be the proper Insert query with select statement inside it?

I tried `selfjoin` too but couldn't get the exact result.

Of course, the foll. query is false but what can be the alterations in this to get the desired query.

```
  string ins3 = "INSERT INTO name (fullname) SELECT firstname + lastname AS fullname FROM name AS name_1 WHERE (firstname = @firstname)  and (lastname = @lastname)";
```

Thanks a ton for going through my question.
Waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a web method as follows

```
public void MethodName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
       string FullName = firstName + lastName;
       /*INSERT (firstName, lastName, FullName) using INSERT QUERY */
}
```

Comment: this was really easy!! I wonder how did I not think of it b4 :)

Answer (score 1):

You need update query, rather than insert:

```
Update name Set Fullname =(SELECT firstname + lastname  FROM name WHERE (firstname = @firstname)  and (lastname = @lastname))
WHERE (firstname = @firstname)  and (lastname = @lastname)
```